# junit on checkstyle extensions

Tags: junit, checkstyle

I would like to write a junit test for my Checkstyle extension.  Can someone show me how to do it?  I know there is a project in github called JUnit-Checkstyle-Test-Wrapper.  However, I don't see how using this tool would help me get to my extension and verify its values.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best reference for how to test your checkstyle extension (I assume you've added a checker) is to look at the [checkstyle source code](http://checkstyle.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/checkstyle/checkstyle/file), and just copy & change one of the existing tests. For example, here is the test for [HeaderCheck](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/test/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/header/HeaderCheckTest.java). This is probably the best way to start. Remember you can actually extend the Checkstyle test classes.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at a lot of examples for custom Checkstyle checks and UTs for them https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle/tree/master/sevntu-checks